# Cannot bind ngModel to p-dropdown value (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I using **PrimeNg** dropdown

Here is html of template

```html
<div>
  <label>{{ l('Portfolio') }}</label>
  <p-dropdown
    [(ngModel)]="property.portfolioId"
    [disabled]="!landlordPortfolios.length"
    [options]="landlordPortfolios"
    autoWidth="false"
    [style]="{ width: '100%' }"
    name="landlordPortfolio"
    [autoWidth]="true"
  ></p-dropdown>
</div>
```

I get values for dropdown via this method

```js
getLandlordPortfoliosById(landlordId: number): void {
  this.landlordPortfolios = [];

  this._landlordPortfolios.getPortfolioDropdownValuesById(landlordId).subscribe(result => {
    result.items.forEach(value => {
      this.landlordPortfolios.push({
        label: value.name,
        value: value.id,
      });
    });
  });
}
```

And call it like this

```js
if (this.property.landlordId) {
  this.getLandlordPortfoliosById(this.property.landlordId);

  this.initLandlordSuggestionsById(this.property.landlordId);
}
```

For example I have `landlordId = 1` and selected option for dropdown must be also with `id = 1`.
Here is result

[image]
But I get selected item in dropdown, just blank field, and I see all options when click dropdown. Where can be my problem?

Comment: Have you imported `FormsModule`

Comment: I don't use forms module, I using primeng stuff @SachinGupta

Comment: How FormsModule  related to this error? @SachinGupta

Comment: How does the variable `result` look like?

Comment: `[(ngModel)]` is related to `FormsModule`

Comment: Okay, great. It imported. If it wasn't I will get error in console, but I didn't get it @SachinGupta

Comment: You can see all options but they are all blank fields?

Comment: I can see options, when I open dropdown, but default option (selected) is blank, so ngModel binding not works. So if ngModel = 1, it must select value with id =1 in dropdown. @DusanRadovanovic

Comment: Shouldn't you change `[(ngModel)]="property.portfolioId"` to `[(ngModel)]="property.landlordId"` then?

Comment: why landlordId, I get portfolios fitering for landlord. So array populated with portfolios.

My problem is not in wrong ngModel, it in ngModel, not bind to dropdown value @DusanRadovanovic

Comment: You haven't set an initial value for `property.portfolioId` anywhere

Answer (score 2):

So problem was in data request/get

if I set `*ngIf` to dropdown, like this `*ngIf = "landlordPortfolios.length"` and delete `[disabled]`, all going well.

Comment: Is old but is gold. thanks